# What is a word/verb or phrase that means "uniting to conquer a goal"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

An example could be:

> These participants are running together to raise awareness and money
>   for cancer research. They are ____________ to conquering cancer.

Comment: In the sense of uniting for a common end, "coalescing" may fit.

Comment: Many seem appropriate: banding together, combining, organizing, joining forces, etc. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! What results did a search in a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/unite) give you? To post an answer on this site you must **include research** or it is off-topic.

Comment: If they were race horses they’d be “[running as one](https://www.gtbets.eu/horsefaq#7) as either a coupled entry (#7) or a field entry (#8) to conquer cancer.”

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, they [*collaborate*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=collaborate&t=crmtb01).

Literally co-labour - work together.

The word is often used in the sense of seeking cures.

Comment: I don't think collaboration is quite right in this case (at least in the example provided), since the people aren't really interacting with each other:  they're all running individually for a single cause.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: The question doesn't say running individually, it says running together.

Comment: I see what you mean...I still think that there isn't sufficient interaction between them to call it "collaboration" though.  I don't mean to sound like I'm attacking you btw, I'm just exploring the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

They are ***contributing*** (towards the common goal).

M-W:

> **[contribute](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contributing)**
>   *verb*
>
> : to give (something, such as money, goods, or time) to help a
>   person, group, **cause**, or organization
>
> : to help to cause something to happen
>
> The volunteers contributed their time towards cleaning up the city.
>
> We're trying to raise money for a new school, and we're hoping that
>   everyone will contribute

.

Answer (score 0):

> They are **cooperating** to conquer cancer.

"Cooperate" definition:  work or act together or jointly for a common purpose or benefit; to associate with another or others for mutual benefit <*nations cooperating to fight terrorism*>

Answer (score 0):

You could say that they are "*[banding together](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/band-together)* to conquer cancer."

> **band together**: to come together as a group in order to achieve something